# Exception handling with default in for expressions

Tags: scala, exception

So folks, I have been trying to convert some Java code samples from a book to idiomatic Scala just to reinforce my Scala learning. I am comfortable with small stuff but seamlessly handling exceptions when using `for` expressions has got me stumped.

The premise is: given a list of host names, retrieve a list of host name / ip address tuple. Sounds simple enough and works fine for good cases i.e.

```
  def printHostInfo(args: Array[String]) {
    val tuples = for {
      arg <- args
      inet <- InetAddress.getAllByName(arg.trim)
    } yield (inet.getHostName, inet.getHostAddress)
    println(tuples mkString "; ")
  }
```

But now comes the hard part: I want to easily deal with exceptions which occur when I input a bad host name. I can use the new `Try` construct but it just dodges the problem.

```
def printHostInfo(args: Array[String]) {
    val tuples = for {
      arg <- args
      inet <- Try(InetAddress.getAllByName(arg.trim)) getOrElse Array()
    } yield (inet.getHostName, inet.getHostAddress)
    println(tuples mkString "; ")
  }
```

In the above snippet, if the host name is bad, the entry is skipped and we are all happy. *But*, what I want to do is in case of a bad host, retrieve a tuple like `(www.hostname.com, Bad host name)`. I tried messing around with `Option` and other stuff but I get compile time errors which I'm not yet qualified to decipher. Can someone suggest a idiomatic solution which is concise and uses the full power offered by Scala? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just move the address resolution to the `yield` expression?

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato: Not sure I understand, maybe you can post an example?

Comment: finally was able to address this, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I originally meant would end something like this:

```
def printHostInfo(args: Array[String]) = {
    val tuples = for {
      arg <- args
    } yield Try[Seq[(String,String)]](InetAddress.getAllByName(arg.trim)
        .map(inet => (inet.getHostName, inet.getHostAddress))) getOrElse List((arg.trim,"Bad host name"))
    println(tuples.flatten mkString ";")
}
```

which is hardly elegant code.

Here's a "functional" redesign that preserves the usage of `Try`:

```
def printHostInfo1(args: Seq[String]) = {
  def hostToTuple(inet: InetAddress) = (inet.getHostName, inet.getHostAddress)

  val hosts = args.flatMap(arg =>
                Try(InetAddress.getAllByName(arg.trim).map(hostToTuple(_)))
                                getOrElse Array((arg.trim,"Bad host name")))

  println(hosts mkString ";")
}
```

Generally, I don't know if I'm explaining this clearly right now, but my point was that you should defer exception handling as far "down" as possible. The problem you've ended up with, in my opinion, is that you handled the exception too early, and now you're stuck with the type system hindering rather than helping you (note: this kind of thing would not be an issue in a language with dynamic typing, such as Python).

In that light, here's a simple iterative alternative:

```
def printHostInfo3(args: Array[String]) {
    val tuples = for(arg <- args)
        yield try {
            for(inet <- InetAddress.getAllByName(arg.trim))
                yield (inet.getHostName, inet.getHostAddress)
        } catch  {
            case e: Exception => Array((arg.trim, "Bad host name"))
        }

    println(tuples.flatten mkString ";")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more thinking, I have finally managed to get it down to a working solution though improvements would be much appreciated:

```
  def printHostInfo(args: Array[String]) {
    val tuples = for {
      arg <- args
      inet <- Try(InetAddress.getAllByName(arg.trim) map
                      (Some(_))) getOrElse Array(None)
    } yield (inet.map(_.getHostName) getOrElse arg,
      inet.map(_.getHostAddress) getOrElse "Host Not Found")
    println(tuples mkString "\n")
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a method which returns an `Either`:

```
def getAllInetAddressesByName(h: String): Either[Exception, List[InetAddress]] ={
  try {
    Right(InetAddress.getAllByName(h).toList)
  } catch {
    case e: UnknownHostException => Left(e)
  }
}
```

which returns either the exception or the addresses. This method converts from a mutable `Array` to an immutable `List` as well. It is the bridge from the Java API (using an exception/array) to functional data types.

With this pattern (using `Either`), you don't need a `Try` later during a mapping or in a for comprehension.

---

So on top of this general method, you could `map` to various result types, for example:

```
val hosts = List("stackoverflow.com", "sdfsdf.sdf", "google.com")

val result = hosts.
  map(host => (host, getAllInetAddressesByName(host))).
  map {
    case (host, Right(addresses)) =>
      (host, addresses.map(a => a.getHostAddress).mkString("/"))
    case (host, Left(ex)) =>
      (host, s"Host $host not found")
  }
```

or using `for`

```
val result = for {
  host <- hosts
} yield {
  (host,
    getAllInetAddressesByName(host).fold(
      ex => s"Host $host not found",
      addresses => addresses.map(a => a.getHostAddress).mkString("/")))
}
```

---

Another example: If you want to `collect` only the good ones:

```
val result = hosts.map(h => (h, getAllInetAddressesByName(h))).collect {
  case (h, Right(addresses)) => 
    (h, addresses.map(a => a.getHostAddress).mkString("/"))
}
```

I had to reformat the code snippets a bit to avoid scrolling.